# Trace inequality for a subset

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\omega$ be a **proper** subset of an open ball $B$, and $\omega$ has a Lipschitz boundary. Is there a some kind of trace inequality which says that $\|u\|_{L^2(\partial B)} \le C \|u\|_{H^1(\omega)}$, where $u$ is continuous, non-zero on the boundary of a ball?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

How would information about $u$ from $\omega$ propagate to $\partial B$ to give you an estimate there? You'd need some pretty special $u$ for this to happen.

As long as there is a point $\zeta\in \partial B$ such that $\operatorname{dist}(\zeta,\omega)>0$, it is easy to construct a function that vanishes on all of $\omega$, yet has nonzero $L^2(\partial B)$ norm.